# Unspecified parameters and return types in kotlin

Tags: function, parameters, kotlin, parameter-passing, return-type

I want to make this function in kotlin with unspecified parameters, and a return type depending on what is entered. That might sound confusing, so heres an example:

```
fun example(variable:unspecified) : variable.type {...}
```

Is there any way to do something like this in kotlin? Im pretty new to this language fyi.

Answer (score 3):

It can be done with the right generics:

```
interface Input<R>

fun <R> example(variable: Input<R>): R {

}
```

This will change the return type based on the generic type passed as `Input`.